# I am trying to use react to create an instance of a Facebook Profile Photo in my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

Hi I am trying to create a instance of a profile photo in react using Facebook Passport I do not know. if I'm properly getting the Json file and then properly mapping it to my component.

I used this as a reference https://www.storyblok.com/tp/react-dynamic-component-from-json

I'm currently working in http://www.passportjs.org

it seems like my block is not exporting for some reason I'm not quite sure what that is

the file I am working off of is https://github.com/Blummer92/learning_react/blob/master/src/passport.js

## Header.js

```
import UserProfile from '../../data/models/UserProfile';
import * as user from 'passport-facebook';
function ProfileDetais() {
  // Try to read user info, although it might not have loaded yet
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
   const user = UserProfile.userId.atributes.id(...user).profile(...user).picture;
```

return  ( ProfileDetail(block))}
              />
    );
      }
    }

## ProfilePhoto.js

```
    import React from 'react';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const ProfilePhoto = () => {};
const Components = {
  profilePhoto: ProfilePhoto,
};

export default block => {
  // component does exist
  if (typeof Components[block.component] !== 'undefined') {
    return React.createElement(Components[block.component], {
      key: block.user,
      block,
    });
  }
};
return React.createElement(
  () => <div>The component {block.component} has not been created yet.</div>,
  { key: block.user },
);
```

Errors

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11


/Users/zachary/WebstormProjects/MyApp/src/components/Header/Header.js
  24:9   error  'user' is already declared in the upper scope  no-shadow
  43:12  error  Insert `·`                                     prettier/prettier

/Users/zachary/WebstormProjects/MyApp/src/components/Header/ProfilePhoto.js
   2:8   error  'UserProfile' is defined but never used                  no-unused-vars
  10:22  error  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  consistent-return
  20:29  error  'block' is not defined                                   no-undef
  21:10  error  'block' is not defined                                   no-undef
```

Comment: It looks like you are getting this error because you might have some files using import which are located outside the path defined in webpack. How are you compiling your code?

Comment: @AliZeaiter I'm not sure what you mean by Compiler?

Comment: Are you using a compiler like babel to convert es6 code like imports to require. Imports and exports are es6 specific and most javascript environments don't really understand them.

Comment: yes I'm using es6 react

Comment: I don't quite understand. You can use es6 with react but a compiler has to be set up in order for the code to work.

Comment: You seem to be using non-es6 code to create your react components but are using the import and export statements which are es6.

Comment: @AliZeaiter I really don't think that is the problem sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202113/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-ali-zeaiter).

Comment: You seem to be using a loader, I suspect as I said earlier that some files using import are located outside the path defined in the configuration file. Which is what 
```SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module``` is probably saying

Comment: @AliZeaiter do you need to see my package.json?